# Determining FinancialData for Countries

Tags: curated-data, date-and-time, finance

How do I determine the `FinancialData` for Australia. For instance the one for USA follows as:

```
FinancialData["NYSE", "Members"]
```

The aim is to perform analysis using the following (plan to substitute "CBA" for "GE", but "CBA" is Australian)

```
DateListPlot[FinancialData["GE", "Volume", {{2000, 1, 1}, {2000, 4, 1}}], 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
FinancialData["AustraliaASX", "Members"]
```

and

```
DateListPlot[
 FinancialData["AX:CBA", "Volume", {{2000, 1, 1}, {2000, 4, 1}}], 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

You can get the names of all available exchanges with

```
FinancialData["Exchanges"]
```