# Accessing the Australian Stock Exchnage through FinancialData

Tags: curated-data, finance

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92210/determining-financialdata-for-countries#_=_) answer from 2015 suggests that data from the Australian Stock Exchange can be accessed using `FinancialData["AX:CBA"]`. However, when I run this I get `Missing [NotAvailible]`. Am I doing something wrong, or has the ASX been quietly removed from Mathematica?

Comment: The Australian stock exchange no longer seems to be listed in `FinancialData["Exchanges"]`.